# How can I run Mist in JSON-RPC mode?

Tags: mist, json-rpc

Or if Mist is simply starting Geth, how can I tell Mist to start Geth in RPC mode?

Answer (score 1):

Run a Geth node on your machine with the configuration options that you require and **then** launch Mist.

Mist will automatically connect to that node.

Get has a number of RPC related [configuration options](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options).